# Twitter share with alternative content

Tags: .htaccess, twitter, expressionengine

Currently we have a page on a client website that is too large for twitter to crawl on share (>1mb).
I want to figure out a way to detect that twitter is crawling the page, and instead serve a limited version of the page.

The website is built in in apache and expressionengine, and so I can use template parsing based on url structure to limit content if necessary.

I also have access to the linux server itself (ssh) if necessary.

So far I am trying to come up with a way to have twitter crawl the url with a query string or something that i can have expression engine listen for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some expression engine addons that allow you to sniff user agents to use as template variables. you can then conditionally display content on whether that user agent is 'Twitterbot'

Example:
https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/browser-detect

Comment: Added this answer, but am leaving it open since a preferable answer would be one that does not use addons. Addons quickly bloat page load times in expression engine.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the alternative would be to enable php in the template and sniff for the user agent that way. However, i think doing this with a plugin would really work better and won't bloat load times at all. 
For more indepth answers, post this question on https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Using an addon now. its not imapcting the load time much (few ms), I just avoid addons as a best practice so that when i do need them I dont need to worry if they will cause problems. Hve seen wp sites in the past use 10+ addons that had minimal impact alone, but together blew up page load times.

Comment: Good answer on php in the template. I hadn't thought of that. I will have non developers with access to the templates though, so I am hesitant to allow php.